# Copying no of files from one folder to another in Mac using terminal

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal

I am trying to follow a blog about machine learning. In the blog, author transferred/copy the certain number of files from one folder to another using linux command. I am working on Mac, I tried to run the commands by modifying them according to the mac environment (with my limited knowledge) but could not able to copy them to other folder. Here is the Linux command copied from the blog

```
#Transfer data into the specific directory
echo "---Parasitized---"
cd Parasitized_all
cp `ls Parasitized_all | head -5000` ../Parasitized_train
cp `ls Parasitized | tail -n+5001 | head -5000 | wc -l` ..Parasitized_validation
cp `ls Parasitized | tail -n+5001 | tail -3779 | wc -l` ..Parasitized_test
```

For instance, I tried to copy the first copy command of above statements into mac as follow:

```
cp `Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_all | head -5000` Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_train
```

However, it did not work. Is there anyone who could guide me in identifying the mistake I am making?

Comment: Based on the examples you've given, you should treat this blog with care.  Follow it at your own risk.  Many bad practices are exhibited above.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

The point of failure comes when you run this:

```
cp `Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_all | head -5000`
```

Because you are trying to do one thing and the shell is understanding another one. By running that `head 5000` you want to read that file `Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_all` and take that list as source to then copy those files that coincide with the first 5.000 lines of it, but `cp` does not work like that, it only understands `copy SOURCE (to) DESTINATION`. Also, it is not even a file but a directory.

The difference between that command and `ls Parasitized_all | head -5000` is that the output from this last command will be a list of files, which can be used as a source for copying them to their destination path.

That said, note that in the command you run you are missing the `ls` at the beginning of it, so that list of files is not coming up. So, try running this instead (I changed from `ls` to `find` just because I prefer using it):

```
cp $(find Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_all -type f | head -5000) Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_train/
```

Or if you face an error like `argument list too long`:

```
for FILE in $(find Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_all -type f | head -5000); do
    cp $FILE Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_train/
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, When I ran the command it throws me this message: -bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long

Comment: In that case, you could try running a loop: `for FILE in $(find Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_all -type f | head -5000); do cp $FILE Documents/folder_directory/Parasitized_train/; done`